# Lisp Infinite Recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I am a new lisp programmer, I am having trouble wrapping my head around recursion in lisp. I have a series of expressions that I simplify by going through a series of methods that replace symbols with numbers and then I will evaluate the expression. Before evaluation I substitute symbols for numbers, in doing that I get a stack overflow error in my subst-bindings method and/or when I call the deep-subst method from within that method. Any help or advice on my recursive method calls that would help me understand better I would greatly appreciate it! My code is below--

```
    (setq p1 '(+ x (* x (- y (/z 2)))))
    (setq p2 '(+ (- z 2) (* x 5)))
    (setq p3 '(+ 1 a))


    (defun deep-subst (old new l)
      (cond
       ((null l) 
         nil
       )
       ((listp (car l))
        (cons (deep-subst old new (car l)) (deep-subst old new (cdr l)))
       )
       ((eq old (car l)) 
        (cons new (deep-subst old new (cdr l)))
       )
       (T   
        (cons (car l) (deep-subst old new (cdr l)))
       )
      )
    )

    (defun subst-bindings (bindinglist exp)
      (cond 
        ( (null bindinglist) 
           exp )
        (T
           (subst-bindings  (cdr bindinglist)(deep-subst (car (car bindinglist)) (cdr (car bindinglist)) exp))
        )
       )
     )

    (defun simplify (exp)
        (cond
         ( (listp exp)
          (simplify-triple (car exp) (simplify (car(cdr exp)))(simplify (car (cdr (cdr exp)))))
        (T
           exp))))

    (defun evalexp (binding-list exp)
        (simplify (subst-bindings binding-list exp))
    )
      (evalexp '( (x 2) (z 8) ) p1)  ;Where I call evalexp from and gives me the stack overflow error
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can show just the smallest amount of code and a test case which reproduce the problem, along with the error message that you receive.  Common Lisp also includes a trace macro, so that if you were to do `(trace deep-subst)`, you'll see all the calls to deep-subst, and you'll probably find the problem.

Comment: I will give the trace a try, I also took out code that was not necessary or helpful to seeing an issue. The last line of code is an example test case where I call evalexp

Comment: I think you may want to debug some more.  The problem doesn't appear to be *solely* in the substitution functions.  E.g., http://pastebin.com/NWHPK5PF runs without a problem (although the result may not be what you expect it to be;  should that bindinglist be `'((x . 2) (z . 8))`?).  That suggests that something is awry in `simplify`.

Comment: Hmmmm very interesting I did not think to cut it all out and test them separately, I believe you are right I need to look at simplify closer.

Comment: @Branbron I'll mention one thing though;  when I ran the sample that I linked to in my previous comment, I noticed that your substitution algorithm takes bindings of the form `(a . b)` to replace a with b.  In the bindings you've used, you'll be replacing x with (2) and z with (8).  Each of those is a list, so there will be more structure that you could recurse on.  It wouldn't be too hard to make a mistake there.

Comment: I am currently tracing it over the simplify method by hand and (trace simplify) with my first binding form, I wonder what effect that will have if I use (a . b). I'll give it a shot since I'm still stuck thanks!

Comment: For future reference, this appears to be based on [CSC344 Assignment 2 \(Lisp\)](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/csc344/a2.html) from Doug Lea's [CSC344](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/csc344/) course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lays in the simplify function as trace proofs

```
(trace simplify)

(evalexp '( (x 2) (z 8) ) p1)
0: (SIMPLIFY (+ (2) (* (2) (- Y (/Z 2)))))
    1: (SIMPLIFY (2))
      2: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
        3: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
          4: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
            5: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
              6: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                7: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                  8: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                    9: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                      10: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                        11: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                          12: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                            13: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                              14: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                                15: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                                  16: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                                    17: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
                                      18: (SIMPLIFY NIL)
```

And if we take a look at the function

```
(defun simplify (exp)
        (cond
          ((listp exp)
           (simplify-triple 
              (car exp) 
              (simplify (car(cdr exp)))
              (simplify (car (cdr (cdr exp)))))
          (T
            exp))))
```

We can see that the recursion is based on the function `listp`. If `listp` returns true then `simplify-triple` will be called which has two calls to `simplify` as parameters. As we can see in the trace `simplify` is called with `nil` over and over again and if we test `(listp nil)` we can see that it returns `T` (which makes [sense](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html) as it represents the [empty list](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node9.html)) therefore leading to the endless recursion.

You'll have to base your recursion on another (or more throughout) if-condition.

Comment: I'll play around with checking the return value in a different way, thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: you could use something like `(and (listp exp) exp)` to ensure that you will not use  `nil` as `and` will interprete `nil` as the boolean false

Comment: The usual way to test for the end of the list is with `endp`.